# How can I retrieve and add certificate from an encrypted .p12 file to iPhone keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

I have an encrypted .p12 file and I am able to import it using the method `**SecPKCS12Import()**`. In the response, I am getting an array(given below).

Import Certificate items Array: (
        {
        chain =         (
            ""
        );
        identity = "";
        trust = "";
    }
)

I go through the apple documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html)

I am able to get the identity, trust and evaluate the trust properly. But I don't how to add the certificate within that identity to the iPhone keychain. I am facing issue in adding the certificate to the keychain.

Can I give an kSecAttrLabel to identify the certificate later.